# virt-install コマンドで仮想マシンの IP アドレスを指定できますか？

Tags: linux

Ubuntu上でvirt-installコマンドを使用してWindowsの仮想マシンを入れているのですが、このコマンドのオプションで、仮想マシンのIPアドレスを指定する方法はありますか？

Comment: `virt-install`コマンドでは指定できないのでは？ (libvirt の別コマンド) `virsh`を使うのではないですか？

Comment: 質問を編集したほうがよいでしょう。何としてでも `virt-install`コマンドが使いたいのか, IPアドレス指定したいだけなのかが質問からは分かりません。(後者と判断し回答したけど) 前者だと「多分ムリ」という回答になるはず。あと, 解決したならばこちらを https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

`virt-install`コマンドではなく, [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/) の別のコマンド, `virsh` で指定するはずです

[libvirt](https://libvirt.org/) ソフトウェア・コレクションの, ネットワークについては [libvirt: NAT forwarding (aka "virtual networks")](https://wiki.libvirt.org/Networking.html) に記されているようです
日本語資料は

- (wikipedia.org) [libvirt](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libvirt)
- (redhat.com) [ゲスト仮想マシンの静的 IP アドレスの設定](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/static-ip-address)

以下はその手順です (redhat.com から)
詳しくは, オリジナルのページを参照してください

○ ゲスト XML 設定ファイルの確認 (`guest1` の代わりに仮想マシンの名前を使用)

```bash
# virsh domiflist guest1
```

○ DHCP 範囲を確認

```bash
# virsh net-dumpxml default | egrep 'range|host\ mac'
```

○ 静的 IP アドレスを設定

```bash
# virsh net-update default add ip-dhcp-host '<host mac="52:54:00:48:27:1D" ip="198.51.100.3"/>' --live --config
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。いただいた情報で実施してみます。